# Given a $4\times 4$ Matrix having $16$ points, what is the probability of making a triangle?

Tags: probability

> Given a $4\times 4$ Matrix having $16$ points, what is the probability of making a triangle from these points?

My Approach:

$4\times 4$ matrix has $16$ points. So, I can choose 3 point of a triangle from these $16$ points= $16\choose 3$

Is this correct?

Comment: How do you make any geometric figure from a matrix, could you elaborate on that? I don't understand what the question is asking.

Comment: Order does matter. Also if all the points are on the same row or column or diagonal ...

Comment: There are many choices of $3$ points from the rectangular array (I would not call it a matrix)  that do not yield a triangle.

Comment: Right, per @AndréNicolas, 'matrix' is poor terminology (even if pretty clear). So, maybe call it a "$4 \times 4$ square grid of 16 points." Must avoid 3 points from the same row, same column, or same diagonal. That's 10 'types' of configurations of 4 points to avoid when choosing 3 for a triangle. Your ${16 \choose 3 }$ possibilities is too many.

Comment: @Bruno Trumbo Not understood clearly.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Not understood please explain in detail :)

Comment: I have written out almost all the details of an answer.

Comment: Great Explanation +2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are presumably choosing $3$ points from the $16$, with all choices equally likely. There are $\binom{16}{3}$ such choices.  To find the probability of making a triangle, we can count the number $F$ of *favourable* choices, where the $3$ points chosen form a triangle. Then the required probability is $\frac{F}{\binom{16}{3}}$.

We can either find $F$ directly, or count the number $B$ of **bad** choices, where the points chosen do not form a triangle, because they lie on a line. Then $F=\binom{16}{3}-B$.

How many ways could we choose badly? To do the counting, it is very useful to draw a careful picture of the $4\times 4$ grid, in order to spot the lines that have $3$ or more points of our grid. Think of the grid points as all points with coordinates $(i,j)$, where $i$ and $j$ are integers with $0\le i\le 3$ and $0\le j\le 3$.

We could choose badly by choosing $3$ points on the top row. There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to do this. Similarly, we could choose $3$ points on the second row, the third, the fourth, the left column, the next column, and so on.  That gives (so far) $8\cdot\binom{4}{3}$ bad choices.

We could also choose badly by choosing $3$ points from the diagonal joining $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$, or from the other long diagonal that joins $(3,0)$ to $(0,3)$. That's $2\cdot \binom{4}{3}$ more bad choices.

That takes care of the lines that have $4$ points of our grid. But there are also lines that have $3$ points of our grid. One example is the line that goes through $(1,0)$, $(2,1)$, and $(3,2)$. By symmetry there are $3$ other such lines. That gives us $4$ more bad choices of $3$ points.

Any others? A careful look at our diagram shows there are no more lines that contain $3$ or more grid points. We end up with $B=44$.